# Optimize join without denormalization

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, join, index-tuning

I have two tables:

```
orders(order_id, scan_timestamp) and
order_products(order_product_id, order_id, pick_number, quantity)
```

and I want to know how many of a particular product (identified by `pick_number`) have been scanned on a particular day:

```
SELECT sum(quantity)
FROM order_products
JOIN orders USING (order_id)
WHERE scan_timestamp >= '2022-04-01T00:00:00.000000+02:00'
AND scan_timestamp < '2022-04-02T00:00:00.000000+02:00'
AND pick_number = '9553'
```

This query is not particularly fast, about 19 ms. This adds up when it's in a subselect and runs for several products.

```
Aggregate  (cost=7577.42..7577.43 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=17.978..17.990 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2027
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=2538.14..7577.20 rows=87 width=4) (actual time=17.341..17.920 rows=83 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (order_products.order_id = orders.order_id)
        Buffers: shared hit=2027
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on order_products  (cost=126.93..5155.66 rows=3936 width=8) (actual time=1.254..7.544 rows=4132 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (pick_number = '9553'::text)
              Heap Blocks: exact=1648
              Buffers: shared hit=1661
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on order_products_pick_number_idx  (cost=0.00..125.94 rows=3936 width=0) (actual time=0.938..0.939 rows=4132 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (pick_number = '9553'::text)
                    Buffers: shared hit=13
        ->  Hash  (cost=2374.37..2374.37 rows=2947 width=4) (actual time=7.222..7.226 rows=2773 loops=1)
              Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 130kB
              Buffers: shared hit=366
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on orders  (cost=66.63..2374.37 rows=2947 width=4) (actual time=0.418..4.169 rows=2773 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: ((scan_timestamp >= '2022-03-31 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (scan_timestamp < '2022-04-01 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                    Heap Blocks: exact=356
                    Buffers: shared hit=366
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on orders_scan_timestamp_idx  (cost=0.00..65.89 rows=2947 width=0) (actual time=0.360..0.360 rows=2773 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((scan_timestamp >= '2022-03-31 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (scan_timestamp < '2022-04-01 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                          Buffers: shared hit=10
```

It kind of makes sense because Postgres has to either go through all orders of a day to find the correct product or it has to go through all the orders of all time of that product to find the correct day.

I found that if I denormalize my data by copying the `scan_timestamp` into `order_products` (and indexing it), I get a massive performance boost (now 1.3 ms):

```
SELECT sum(quantity)
FROM order_products
WHERE order_scan_timestamp >= '2022-04-01T00:00:00.000000+02:00'
AND order_scan_timestamp < '2022-04-02T00:00:00.000000+02:00'
AND pick_number = '9553'
```

```
Aggregate  (cost=190.68..190.69 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.952..0.956 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=90
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on order_products  (cost=110.19..190.63 rows=21 width=4) (actual time=0.737..0.885 rows=83 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((order_scan_timestamp >= '2022-03-31 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (order_scan_timestamp < '2022-04-01 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (pick_number = '9553'::text))
        Heap Blocks: exact=39
        Buffers: shared hit=90
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on order_products_order_scan_timestamp_pick_number_index  (cost=0.00..110.19 rows=21 width=0) (actual time=0.717..0.718 rows=83 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((order_scan_timestamp >= '2022-03-31 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (order_scan_timestamp < '2022-04-01 22:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (pick_number = '9553'::text))
              Buffers: shared hit=51
```

Is there anything else I can do instead of denormalizing?

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: "*This adds up when it's in a subselect and runs for several products.*" - maybe the solution is to not run it in a sub-select once for each product, but use a derived table that calculates this for all needed product in a single query.

Comment: To add to @a_horse_with_no_name, the plan looks like it’s already doing a lot of the work it would be doing when you need to look at more pick_numbers. You can either optimize it so that the individual execution is fast (look at how you’re indexing each table) or optimize it so your real query is fast (write the query so that it only needs to do the work once)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `order_products.order_id` references `orders.order_id`

Comment: Not having it in a subselect is a good workaround but it means having to maintain more specialized queries instead of plugging in this subselect where it's needed.

Comment: Also, being able to optimize such a basic join would be quite valuable in general. I would argue that the immense speedup could justify having a denormalization feature in Postgres itself.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the query looks like it is running well. Is the problem that you call it from the client for many different values of `pick_number`, or is it part of a bigger query? Please be more specific about that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Both, and I can come up with workarounds in both cases, but just in general I think 16 ms is a lot, especially since it obviously is possible to get this from an index in 1 ms by denormalizing.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to be more specific, then all I can say is that there is no way to make that query faster as it is.

Comment: You should turn on track_io_timing if it is not on already, then do EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS).

Comment: "could justify having a denormalization feature in Postgres itself."  What would such a feature look like?  How would it be different from just making your model denormalized yourself?

Comment: @jjanes Like a [generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) but one that can pull data from another table.

Comment: @jjanes I have updated the above plans with the BUFFERS results.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing IO is often a good starting point, but in your case all of your buffers are "Hit", so there is nothing there to optimize.

You can denormalize your data "automatically" by using a functional index.  This does involve declaring a function as "immutable" when it might not truly be immutable.  So there is a risk there that you might get mild corruption (wrong answers from queries using the index) if orders.scan_timestamp ever changes after it was already used in order_products.  You could try to mitigate this with some trigger on orders, but then you would probably have race conditions of both tables are being changed at the same time.

```
create function get_scan(int) returns timestamptz language sql immutable parallel safe as $$
    select scan_timestamp from orders where order_id=$1
$$;

create index on order_products (pick_number , get_scan(order_id);
```

Then the corresponding query would be:

```
SELECT sum(quantity)
FROM order_products
WHERE  get_scan(order_id) >= '2022-04-01T00:00:00.000000+02:00'
AND get_scan(order_id) < '2022-04-02T00:00:00.000000+02:00'
AND pick_number = '8853';
```

You could instead use an actual column to order_products, using the same function define above (with the same caveat about immutability) in a GENERATED expression, and then use a regular (not function-based) index including that column.  A downside to that is that you are storing the denormalized data an extra time, both in the table and in the index.  Plus you now have a column showing up in the table that would need to be documented as not really belonging there.  The benefit though is that you could get an index-only scan in situations where you might not be able to get one with functional index.

Comment: In my case `scan_timestamp` can certainly change after `order_products` are inserted, so a one-time copy is not enough. I'm not worried about the extra column (I'll just call it `_cache` and everyone working on the code will know why it's there), but I really wish I could tell Postgres to keep it up-to-date automatically. I think I will explore the trigger approach, but I'll probably need a bunch of different triggers (on `orders` update, on `order_products` update, on `order_products` insert, maybe others I haven't realized yet).